# BF CLI parsing error on exported QnA maker knowledge base

Tags: azure-qna-maker

**We need a fix related the the following parsing error when QnA maker KB are exported via BL CLI**

We use the BF CLI (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/botframework-cli) with the @next version to export QnA maker KB in *.qna format and then generate the snapshot for the BF orchestrator.

The command used to export the QnA maker KB is:

```
bf qnamaker:kb:export --out=.\cognitiveModels\q_IT.qna --kbId=a238d6ac-XXXX-YYY-9fdd-28e335030610 --subscriptionKey=d01228763e**** --qnaFormat
```

The command used to generate the snapshot is:

```
bf orchestrator:create --hierarchical --in ./dataSources --out ./generated --refresh
```

Generation of the snapshot fails due to a parsing error and displays the following error message

```
undefined
Failed to parse C:\GitHub-local\To-trash\orchestrator\dataSources\q_IT.qna
```

We identified that the parsing error comes from a specific line on the q_IT.qna file - Here is the original code and the modified version:

Orignal (automatically generated via the bf qnamaker:kb:export command)

```
**Prompts:**
- [What Should You Sync](#782)
- [Files that Cannot Sync
](#783)
- [Box Sync Status](#784)
```

Manual modification to fix the parsing issue:

```
**Prompts:**
- [What Should You Sync](#782)
- [Files that Cannot Sync](#783)
- [Box Sync Status](#784)
```

The problem is generated by the bf qna:bf:export cli command - **We need a fix for that.**

Here are screenshots with the content of QnA maker portal and the QnA pair associated to this parsing error.
[QnA maker portal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q9jY.png)

Comment: Hi, did you get any fix to this issue. I have the same problem

Comment: We are aware of the issue and tracking the issue here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/1294. Thanks!